# asset size for maximum Android screen width

Tags: android, image, android-assets

I am preparing some images assets to be downloaded from a back end service, the assets will be used on android and iphone,

I need to get the images looking ok on phablets, on the current iPhone retina display the width is 640 px

so what would be a proper width for my images so they can look good on Android wider screens?
and not become to huge [kb size]?, as i need to download many images on my requests?

I have checked sizes and looks like nexus 7: 1200pxW X1920pxH could be the biggest size?

what is the minimum width for an image I can get away with that will look ok on a wide android phone?

Comment: This may help you out a bit. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html . 
    
If you have things like logos and loading screens you're concerned about set the bgcolor to a solid and center a smaller image. That way you don't have to worry so much about stretching.     
    
At the moment 1200pxW maybe good enough for current tablets but that will most likely change in the coming years with the release of new devices.